# Tkinter Enter widget is not taking input into floating number

Tags: python, api, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm using an `API` to convert one unit to another. I'm trying to get input from user by "Entry Widget" as floating number. This is my code.

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def pressMe():
        out_entry.insert(1, f'{result}')

in_entry = tk.Entry(root)
in_entry.pack()

out_entry = tk.Entry(root)
out_entry.pack()

but = tk.Button(root, command=pressMe)
but.pack()
val = float(in_entry.get())
url1 = "https://measurement-unit-converter.p.rapidapi.com/length/units"

querystring = {"value":val,"from":"km","to":"m"}
headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "0760466864***********************4jsnb3eaeb63d084",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "measurement-unit-converter.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url1, headers=headers, params=querystring)

data = response.json()
result = data['result']

root.mainloop()
```

In here I'm making first entry widget `in_entry` by which I can take input and the second one `out_entry` to show the output, one button is made to do so. But I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\5ht project\check.py", line 290, in <module>
    val = float(in_entry.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I know that this problem is because I'm trying to convert the empty string into float which is not possible. But I'm not able to find any solution to this. Is there any way by which I can have input from user by `in_entry` and after that I can use that value in `API` which can return me the converted value, and then I can insert this converted value to the second entry widget `out_entry`. Hope you get my question.

This is the link of `API` I'm using.
https://rapidapi.com/me-Egq5JBzo4/api/measurement-unit-converter/

Comment: You are calling `.get()` on your Entry a millisecond or so after it was created - it's not physically possible for the user to have typed in anything yet!  You need to do the `.get()`, and anything that uses the value, from within your Button's `command=` function.

Comment: @jasonharper Sorry but I didn't get what actually you are trying to say. Or you are saying that I should get the entry widget value in the ```pressMe``` function?

Answer (score 0):

it is as jasonharper said: "You are calling .get() on your Entry a millisecond or so after it was created - it's not physically possible for the user to have typed in anything yet!"

what you can do:

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

in_entry = tk.Entry(root)
in_entry.pack()

out_entry = tk.Entry(root)
out_entry.pack()

url1 = "https://measurement-unit-converter.p.rapidapi.com/length/units" #this is a constant, isn't it?

def pressMe(): # the in entry must be above because this function it will get the value
        val = float(in_entry.get()) # you get the value here to make sure the user has clicked the button (then you know there is a number in the entry)
        querystring = {"value":val,"from":"km","to":"m"}
        headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "0760466864***********************4jsnb3eaeb63d084",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "measurement-unit-converter.p.rapidapi.com"
        } # maybe also a constant? you can this piece of code also place at the top of your program

        response = requests.request("GET", url1, headers=headers, params=querystring)

        data = response.json()
        result = data['result'] #here i get an keyerror because i'm not subscribed
        
        out_entry.insert(1, f'{result}')

but = tk.Button(root, command=pressMe) # the button is created here, because its command is pressme. for that, it's really important that it is below pressme
but.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

then  i can't help you further because the only thing i get from your url is:

```
{'message': 'You are not subscribed to this API.'}
```